# How read data from file and execute to MYSQL?

Tags: php

I create form to load sql file and used fopen function top open file and read this but when want to execute this data to database not work? 
What is wrong in my code?

```
$ofile      =   trim(basename($_FILES['sqlfile']['name']));
$path = "sqlfiles/".$ofile;
//$data = settype($data,"string");
$file = "";

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$selectdb = mysql_select_db('files');


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['sqlfile']['tmp_name'],"sqlfiles/".$ofile))
  {
    $path = "";
  }

  $file = fopen("sqlfiles/".$ofile,"r") or exit("error open file!");

  while (!feof($file))
  {
    $data = fgetc($file);
    settype($data,"string");
    $rslt = mysql_query($data);
    print $data; 
  }

  fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: You have security issues.  I don't know enough PHP to tell you exactly what they are.

Comment: @Ninefingers - answer or don't answer, as you wish.  But voting ought to reflect the merits of the question, not the civic qualities of the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should use [fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) instead of fgetc while youre reading lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your script assumes that there is exactly one SQL statement per line, with no blanks or comments. If this is not the case then you'll need to either read and parse the file manually, or redirect the file to the `mysql` executable and let it handle the SQL statements.